# C#/Java Best practice to save data locally

Tags: java, c#

Lets say I want to make a program on c#.net for a video club to store clients and theirs rents.
What is the best and modern way (and standalone way) to store this data? xml, binary seriliazation, sqlite, access?

I will also need to query often the data. For example a client come, I search him via name, I find him and I add him a new rent. Also (now or on future) there will be data for dvds too (add dvds and on short there will relation between dvds and clients). Its like a database but because database is not standalone I want my program works only if user have on his pc .net installed. I could use mysql but this needs mysql server installed...

What you think is the best and most modern solution?

Comment: First you have to decide whether you are gonna code in C# or Java. They look alike, but are different things, you know?

Comment: MySQL is a free install.  why not use it.  Is this a web app?  You could look into JSON/jquery to write/read data to an XML file.  You could create a DAO class so that if youd decide to replace with a database it would be easier to plug in.  Also you net to decide if its Java or C#.  If Java you will want to use Hibernate to write and read easily to your database - if its C# you want to use Linq.

Comment: Its not a web application. Its window forms application that will save data locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

various sql's are good enuff: sqlite, sql ce, sql express.

Access may be the easiest starting solution as you can visualise the data without much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

if it is not critical data, simply store it in an xml or json file using xml to object mapping like JAXB or xsd.exe or JSON to object mapping like GSON.

If it is critical best is to go with DB.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a small solution use either ms sql express or mysql. Both should be free (as in free beer).

Sql express is best for .net, mysql for java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded database.  If you don't like SQL databases (some can be embedded) you can try one of the many free "NoSQL" database http://nosql-database.org/ has a list of 122.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is the simplest which works.  I don't think the most modern is necessarily going to be the best.  For example, I'd be looking at the number of members.  Is this number as big as from a large movie store chain? Or is for a small group of people?  If only a small number, is it possible for you to use Excel or similar?

Are you choosing C# because you want to learn it or are you driven by the end result. i.e. a working and useful asset tracking system? (Which many already exist of course)

Other than that, many databases can be stored in a single file and are quite easy to create.  I think there is an flat file driver for SQLite, and JDBC certainly has one.

You may also wish to consider the need to inform your members of your privacy policy with dealing with their personal information (eg. How do you keep private Mr Bloggs's dirty movie rental collection).  We often forget this stuff in our eagerness for creating a cool application!

Good luck!